# Inline embed field doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, embed, discord, discord.js

After having done an update of Node.js, embeds don't work correctly now...
I tried to reinstall node.js and discord.js but nothing happened. I also tried to rewrite the code but it's the same thing, inline embeds don't work...

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true})
const prefix = "&"

client.on("message", message => {

    if (message.content === prefix + "test") {
        let myembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setAuthor("AUTHOR", message.author.avatarURL)
        .setFooter("FOOTER", client.user.avatarURL)
        .setTimestamp(new Date())
        .setTitle("TITLE")
        .addField("FIELD 1", "SUBFIELD 1", true)
        .addField("FIELD 2", "SUBFIELD 2", true)
        message.channel.send(myembed)
    }
})

client.login("token")
```

And this is what I have:

[image: And this is what I have]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug version 11.4.0, he is already known and will be fixed in the next version. You can revert to the previous version by writing to the console `npm i discord.js@11.3.2`

Comment: thanks for your answer. And yeah, it's a bug from the version. Thank you